# How can I perform perfect forwarding without using templates?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want perfect forwarding but I already know (and only accept) the type my function will take.

Here is a quick example I typed up:

```
class big_class
{
private:
    std::string m_somethingBig;
};

class testmove
{
public:

    void Add(big_class&& big)
    {
        std::cout << "Add via move\n";
        m_bigClasses.push_back(std::move(big));
    }

    void Add(big_class const& big)
    {
        std::cout << "Add via copy\n";
        m_bigClasses.push_back(big);
    }

private:

    std::vector<big_class> m_bigClasses;
};

int main()
{
    testmove tm;

    big_class big;
    tm.Add(big);

    tm.Add(big_class{});
}
```

[Live Sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48a8c0ab77503923)

Is it possible to do some form of implementation sharing between the two overloads of `testmove::Add()`? I want to optimize for move, and if someone does `std::move()` without my rvalue overload it will end up doing at least 1 copy before it is added to my vector.

Again, I realize I can solve this problem by making Add() a template function, and even using type traits and some template trickery. But I wanted to avoid this if possible. If you need to know why, I have a few reasons:

- I can't do implementation hiding with a template (restrict includes and symbol visibility to a single translation unit)
- Using a template here gives me more flexibility than I want (My contract requires I only use a `big_class`).
- Using a template would impact readability/maintainability for what should be a simple interface.

Comment: Just use a by-value parameter and move from it in the implementation.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you don't need `std::move` since `big` has type `big_class&&` already. Only thing `std::move` does is cast to an rvalue-reference.

Comment: @Kostas you wrong. Named rvalue is lvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach suggested by Xeo (take the parameter by value) is the one I would strongly recommend. However, if for some reason you can't do that (*e.g.,* moves are expensive but less so than copies), keep reading.

I think it's possible to satisfy all your criteria, but it's only worth it if the code is complicated enough so that duplicating it would be bad. The idea is to delegate to a template that will be explicitly instantiated only for `big_class`.

`big_class.h`:

```
// ...
public:
    void Add(big_class&& big)
    {
        Add_internal(std::move(big));
    }
    void Add(big_class const& big)
    {
        Add_internal(big);
    }
private:
    // not part of interface; defined in .cpp file
    template <typename T> void Add_internal(T&& big);
```

`big_class.cpp`:

```
// implementation of template
template <typename T> void big_class::Add_internal(T&& big) {
    // shared logic goes here
    m_bigClasses.push_back(std::forward<T>(big));
}
// explicit instantiation
template void big_class::Add_internal<big_class>(big_class&&);
template void big_class::Add_internal<big_class const&>(big_class const&);
```

Comment: Since `Add_internal` is a normal perfect forwarding template, you don't need to provide explicit template arguments when calling it.

Comment: if the cost of moving an argument is your biggest performance problem, you're in a very good place...

Comment: @RichardHodges Where did I say it was the biggest performance problem?

Comment: @void.pointer you didn't. Brian mentioned the (miniscule) expense of a move in the (elided) copy-move idiom, which would be the recommendation.

Comment: Actually the copy is the solution I chose for this. It was eye opening to realize how I was seriously over-thinking this problem. However, I do like your alternative solution which does in fact solve the implementation sharing aspect of my question (assuming I couldn't have done the copy, for whatever reason).

Answer (score 1):

if you really can't stand the idea of adding by value, you may provide one internal templated impl:

```
private:
    template<class X>
    auto add_impl(X&& x) {
        m_bigClasses.push_back(std::forward<X>(x));
    }

public:

    void Add(big_class&& big)
    {
        std::cout << "Add via move\n";
        add_impl(std::move(big));
    }

    void Add(big_class const& big)
    {
        std::cout << "Add via copy\n";
        add_impl(std::move(big));
    }
```

> How can this work? you're moving a const ref!

Because `std::move` does not move anything. It merely casts an l-value reference to an r-value reference. So `const T&` becomes a `const T&&`, which no-one ever codes for. So it will decay to match the `const T&` or `T` that people do code for.

Comment: What is gained by putting `std::move` around the const ref? The object is going to be copied either way.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The OP's question was this: "Is it possible to do some form of implementation sharing between the two overloads of testmove::Add()"? I merely answered the OP's question. `it's not for me to tell him that it's a waste of time.

Comment: When you say implementation sharing, are you referring to the fact that both of your Add overloads have the same line, (`add_impl(std::move(big));`) even though it's typed twice? Or are you referring to the `add_impl` funciton template itself?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley presented with a question (for a solution to an artificial problem) I simply sought to come up with the best answer. For me, the best answer is the one which requires least thought on behalf of the implementor while still producing optimal code, since this reduces the chance for a mistake. Specifically disallowed from doing the right thing (a template function on the interface), I did what I thought was the next best thing - sharing a private implementation while the necessary glue code is exactly the same - i.e. requiring least cognitive activity.